# adf faces setting default username password on login page

Tags: java, jsp, authentication, oracle-adf

I have the code bellow in jsp for authenticating on a portal, and I would like to set the username and password, so the user only type submit...
I tried changing the value e.g value="guest" but don't pass validation...
Any help on that?
thanks

```
                           <af:panelLabelAndMessage
                                    label="#{WebPortalAuth.webAuthConfigPage.loginPageUserNameLabel}"
                                    for="webPortalAuthUsername">
                                    <af:inputText id="webPortalAuthUsername"
                                        value="#{WebPortalAuth.userName}"
                                        inlineStyle="margin-left: 0px; width: 220px">
                                        <v:validateUserName />
                                    </af:inputText>
                                </af:panelLabelAndMessage>

                                <af:panelLabelAndMessage
                                    label="#{WebPortalAuth.webAuthConfigPage.loginPageUserPasswordLabel}"
                                    for="webPortalAuthPassword">
                                    <af:inputText secret="true" id="webPortalAuthPassword"
                                        inlineStyle="margin-left: 0px; width: 220px"
                                        value="#{WebPortalAuth.password}" />
                                </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to associate this page content with a backing bean where you set the values of username and password for example:

```
RichInputText webPortalAuthUsername;
RichInputText webPortalAuthPassword;
```

You add the getters and setters then in an page int method you could write:

```
public void initPhase(PhaseEvent phaseEvent) {

    webPortalAuthUsername.setValue("your_username_here");
    webPortalAuthPassword.setValue("your_password_here");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that there're getter and setter methods of userName and password values, and write a post construct method in the managed bean.

```
@PostConstruct
private void initializeManagedBean() {
    userName = "your_username"; 
    password = "your_password";
}
```